# Getting HTTP 405 error at every request with Nginx and React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, nginx

I have my backend listening on port 8000 and my front end is served on port 80 with Nginx, but since I use this, every request to my backend gives a 405 error.
My front end is working properly. Just when I have to retrieve elements by sending a request to the backend, I get only error 405

Nginx configuration:

```
upstream node_server {
    server node-api:8000;
    keepalive 8;
}
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name localhost;
  index index.html;
  
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
  
  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    try_files $uri /index.html =404;
  }
  location /api {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

      proxy_pass http://node_server/;
      proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

Dockerfile Backend

```
FROM node:16.18

RUN mkdir backend 
COPY package*.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . /backend

WORKDIR /backend

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Dockerfile FrontEnd

```
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine as builder

WORKDIR /app

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH


COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.4.1 -g --silent

COPY . ./

RUN npm run build


FROM nginx:1.23.2-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html

COPY --from=builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Docker compose:

```
version: "3"
services:
  react:
    build:
      context: front_end/
    ports: 
      - "80:80"
  backend:
    build:
      context: backend/
    ports: 
      - "8000:8000"
    container_name: node-api
    volumes:
      - ./backend/:/backend/
```

font_end/src/setupProxy.js

```js
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require("http-proxy-middleware");

module.exports = function (app) {
  app.use(
    "/",
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: "http://node-api:8000",
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
};
```

For the requests in react I do :

```js
fetch("/check-date", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        project: project_encrypted,
        date: date_encrypted,
      }),
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
      },
    })
```

i tried with :

```js
fetch("/api/check-date", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        project: project_encrypted,
        date: date_encrypted,
      }),
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
      },
    })
```

Comment: 405 typically means, you are using the wrong method, ie for instance sending a POST request, where only GET is allowed ...

Comment: How can I authorize a post? I guess it's from Nginx because before I could